# Scene where monster inside a toilet is shot

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

There's a scene where a creature explodes along with a toilet when fired at with a shotgun. This is from a (B?)movie with small carnivorous creatures. It's definitely not in the Gremlins although there might be similar scenes. I'm undecided as to whether it's in Ghoulies, Critters or another movie. Does this ring a bell for anyone ?

Comment: when i was about 4yo my friend had these gnarly little monster finger puppets.  for a few weeks i was secretly very worried that some little creature like that would pop out of the toilet.

Comment: Lol, avoid watching Ghoulies then :p

Comment: There's a vaguely similar scene Stephen King's *[Dreamcatcher](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0285531/)*

Comment: Sounds like Critters to me.

Comment: @cjstehno So it is. I've posted to an excerpt from the movie below.

Comment: [Ghoulies 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RmBQarrygY) is the other famous toilet scene from the era

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found it. It's from Critters, apparently released in 1986. Here's a video showing the scene in question.

[Critter gets shot by a bounty hunter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_II-T_fzuA&feature=player_detailpage#t=299s)